# How can I use a for loop to modify a variable inside a string while I download a list of images using BS?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urlretrieve

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape a page with a table. When I am going to download some images inside that table using  a for loop and "urlretrieve", I am not able to give each image a different name, thus the each time an image is downloaded, it is replaced by a new image because they have the same name.

In other words, I am not able to change a variable inside a string so that I can give each downloaded image a different name.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add code in a code block in questions, so they are not reliant on the picture link being up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last picture, you are setting num to 0 at each loop iteration. You want to take it out of the loop.

```
for ...
  num=0
```

to

```
num = 0
for ...
  num += 1
```